# CSS for background changing over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make the body background changing over time ? 
I need some code that it could help me with this case

Does any body here know ?
If so, please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have an background files as image1.jpg, image2.jpg and so on. use following code to achieve you goal.

```
var count = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    $("body").css("background", "url(image"+ count +".jpg)")
    count++;
},30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to use specific styles you could write css for the styles and then use javascript to change the class.

CSS:

```
.styleNumberOne
{
background:red;
}
.styleNumberTwo
{
background:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html><head>...</head>
<body onload="function(){setInterval(changeStyle(), 3000);}">....</body></html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var styleUsed="styleNumberOne";

function changeStyle(){
   document.body.className = styleUsed;
   if(styleUsed === "styleNumberOne"){
      styleUsed = "styleNumberTwo";
   } else{
      styleUsed = "styleNumberOne";
   }
}
```